# fatal error when reloading table data: unwraps to nil: need assistance

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

The app that I am developing has a table view. It seems like I made a mistake when printing the table view cell values, because whenever I reload the table data when the app is running, I get a fatal error, unexpectedly found nil in unwrapping. This is happening because there's an error in the table code. Help would be appreciated, thanks.
Entire code:
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
var arr = [Int]()
var timer = NSTimer()
var countdowntimer = NSTimer()
var count = 0
var countdown = Int(arc4random_uniform(4000) + 1000)
var highscore:Int!
var buttonTapCounter = 0
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()


@IBOutlet weak var beginButton: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var resetDataButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var averageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bestLabel: UILabel!





@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var highScoreButton: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

func updateTime() {
    countdown = countdown - 1
    if countdown <= 0 {
        startButton.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        startButton.text = "Tap Now!"
        countdowntimer.invalidate()
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "red")
        count = 0
        Timer()
    }
}

func Timer() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target:self, selector:Selector("reflexTest"), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)

}

func reflexTest() {
    count = count + 1
    timerLabel.text = "\(count) ms"
}



@IBAction func returnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonTapCounter = 0
}


@IBAction func scoreButtonTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonTapCounter = 0
    table.reloadData()
//THE table.reloadData() UP HERE IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM.
//I AM TYPING
//LIKE THIS SO YOU WILL
//NOTICE AS YOU SCROLL
//SORRY
//I AM TYPING
//LIKE THIS SO YOU WILL
//NOTICE AS YOU SCROLL
//SORRY
}

@IBAction func beginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if startButton.text == "Tap when the Color Changes" {
        startButton.text = "You tapped too early!"
        countdowntimer.invalidate()
        countdown = Int(arc4random_uniform(4000) + 1000)
    } else {
        if count == 0 {
            countdowntimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            startButton.text = "Tap when the Color Changes"
            countdown = Int(arc4random_uniform(4000) + 1000)
            timerLabel.text = "\(count) ms"
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "green")
            startButton.text = "Tap to Begin"
            arr.append(count)
            count = 0
            highscore = minElement(arr)
            highScoreButton.text = "Best: \(highscore)"
            saveDefaults()

        }

    }

}

func loadDefaults() {

    if let savedArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("data") as? [Int] {
    self.arr = savedArray
    }
}
func saveDefaults() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.arr, forKey: "data")

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"
    let dateInFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    var tableArray:[Int]! = arr
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(tableArray[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadDefaults()

    highscore = minElement(arr)
    if buttonTapCounter == 0 {
        highScoreButton.text = "Best: \(highscore)"
    }



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

The code that needs fixing is probably this chunk:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"
    let dateInFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    var tableArray:[Int]! = arr
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(tableArray[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

Once again, thank you everyone, and remember: the error found nil while unwrapping optional value has to do with the table. Thanks!

Comment: nope. doesn't work :(. The problem is somewhere in String(tableArray[indexPath.row]) ..it found an error while unwrapping there. It means I most likely have to add an explanation mark somewhere, and I don't know where, and am having trouble.

Comment: log your tableArray and check that its nil or not....

Comment: What's the purpose of this : var tableArray:[Int]! = arr ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your array(arr). Print arr in console.
I tried your code by taking a static integer array and it works fine.